# Navigation Controllers in Swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigationcontroller

I have embedded my story board view controllers with the navigation controller. However, I want one view specific controller to not have the navigation bar. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hide the navigation bar in viewWillAppear.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}
```

Also, make sure you have it appear again when you leave that particular view controller. I usually do this in viewWillDisappear.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}
```